# Providing input to a program started from a Python script

Tags: python

I'm working with yolov3. I created a python script for triggering yolov3. When this code worked. The program wants an image path like the following image. My question is how can give this path from the python side and hit enter automatically.

[image]

```
import os

commands = './darknet detector test cfg/car-obj.data car-yolov3.cfg weights/car-yolov3_50000.weights -dont_show'
os.system(commands)
```

Comment: That's input to the `darknet` command you're running? You *can* get a stdin handle (use `subprocess`, not `os.system()`), but better is to fix the command so it can take the value you want on the command line, if in fact it can't already. (It's very unusual for well-designed UNIX commands to *require* TTY input without any means of programmatic use).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't really trying to interact with the *terminal*, but want to interact with your subprocess's *stdin*. That file handle is attached to the terminal by default<sup>[1]</sup>, but you can also have it be attached to a FIFO that your Python script can write to.

Using modern Python 3 facilities (`subprocess.run()` with the `input` argument), this might look like:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.run(['./darknet', 'detector', 'test',
                    'cfg/car-obj.data', 'car-yolov3.cfg', 'weights/car-yolov3_50000.weights',
                    '-dont_show'], input='Image Path\n')
```

---

<sub>[1] - Well, it's inherited from the program that started it, so if you started Python in a terminal, any program *it* starts in turn will get its stdin from that same terminal... unless any program in the chain redirects it.</sub>